# Word VBA: How to Delete Shapes (horizontal line)?

Tags: vba, ms-word, line, shapes

Trying to find all horizontal lines in a Word document and delete them. Having some trouble... any help is appreciated. Code below.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim oShp As Shape
Dim i As Long

With ActiveDocument
    For i = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            oShp.Select
            Selection.Delete
        End With
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just iterate the inlineShapes collection and delete only the shapes whose type is an horizontal line.

```
Public Sub DeleteHorizontalLines()

    Dim docShape As InlineShape
    
    For Each docShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    
        If docShape.Type = wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine Then
            docShape.Delete
        End If
        
    Next docShape

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

EDIT: To replace the shape with a text, you could add the text before deletin it.

Add this line:

```
docShape.Range.InsertAfter "Horizontal line"
```

Before this line:

```
docShape.Delete
```

Comment: This did work. Thank you! How about instead of deleting the shape entirely, we replace the shape with a string "horizontal line"? I do not see any function for replace under .docShape

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Worked flawlessly